# When I use CreateWizard how do I create a profile along with it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use profiles in my CreateWizard, but I cant seem to find a good tutorial on how to do this.  I would think that its the most logical way when you want to add profiles is to add a profile after the user is created.  Ive been researching using ProfileCommon to create a profile and store it.  Basically, I just cant find a way to add the profile when the user is created so I can have custom fields in my accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some posts on this.

checkout painfreeods.peterkellner.net

and

http://peterkellner.net/2006/03/13/adding-personalization-via-profiles-to-the-objectdatasource-in-aspnet-20/